# class.getResourceAsStream returns null when looking for a properties file in same package

Tags: java, netbeans, properties, path

I have a class that loads its properties file using class.getResourceAsStream(props.properties).  The properties file is in the same package as the class itself, yet it is now returning null rather than the object.  I am frazzled because this works fine on an original computer, yet fails on a different computer.  I copied the entire directory structure over from the old to the to new.  I'm using Netbeans 7.2.1 on both computers.  I'm sure its got to be a classpath setting or SOMETHING but I cant find any differences between the two environments whatsoever.  Here's sample code:

```
package Cab;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CabTest{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties  l_Prop = new Properties();
        InputStream l_IS;
        try
        {
           l_IS = CabTest.class.getResourceAsStream("props.properties");
           l_Prop.load(l_IS);
        }
        catch(IOException l_Exc)
        {
            System.out.println(l_Exc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That will look for `java/lang/props.properties` (i.e. relative to `java.lang.Class`).  Presumably you meant `CabTest.class`.

Comment: Correctamundo - I cut-n-pasted on this new laptop, the ctrl key is ever-so-slightly moved from the old keyboard... and I erased CabTest.class.  I mistyped when I just retyped what I had erased.  Above corrected.

Comment: Ok, got it to work by adding every single path in the hierarchy to the classpath.... which OBVIOUSLY is not a viable solution... its got to be something screwy in Netbeans..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This says that if the .class file is in package "foo.bar.baz.props.properties", then that's the path you ought to give to the classloader:

```
l_IS = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo/bar/baz/props.properties");
```

Your way will work only if it's at the root of the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Note the static context. I missed that too!

Comment: K - I cannot explain why this works on my original computer and not on the new one... but by adding .../<pkg>/src to the classpath, it works.  I understand why that works, per-se, but I can't understand why the old computer does NOT have that in the classpath, yet it works fine.  Same vs Netbeans, same vs of Java, same everything.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Does this really work on one env and not another? It doesn't look right since this

```
l_IS = Class.class.getResourceAsStream("props.properties");
```

doesn't resolve to a stream related to your particular class. Try:

```
l_IS = CabTest.class.getResourceAsStream("props.properties");
```

Comment: Class.class was a typo when I transcribed to here (new laptop, fat-fingered the keys).  But yes, CabTest.class. works fine on the old computer and not on the new one.